# Compress/uncompress LZMA strings in Java

Tags: java, string, lzma

On the client side, I have [LZMA-JS](https://github.com/nmrugg/LZMA-JS) compressing plain text and sending it to the server as an string. So far, all LZMA Java implementations I've found takes a File or InputStream as argument. Is there any implementation that uses String directly as input or should I write an InputStream String wrapper around the data goten from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your String in an InputStream:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    lzmaString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
);
```

Now you can use the String as the source for the InputStream that the library wants to consume.